# Conditionally Exit Camel Loop

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'll start off by saying that I'm using Camel 2.14, upgrading is simply not in the cards at the moment.  So I miss out on the doWhile option which came in 2.17.

I have a scenario in which I need to be able to have the routing repetitively attempt to deliver to a service instance when it is ready.  Once this succeeds then I need to exit the loop.  So far I have been able to look a specified number of times.  However, that loop continues even after success.

I've searched through and it appears I don't have many options.  Or I'm still too new at the Camel realm to recognize my options.

```
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:myQueue" />
    <loop>
        <simple>100</simple>
        <when>
             <simple>${bean:myService?method=isReady}</simple>
             <to uri="bean:myService?method=doWork" />
        </when>
    </loop>
</route>
```

Comment: Is the point of the loop to add a delay mechanism?

Comment: No the point is to wait until the service is ready for processing. It's a retry mechanism to make the test repeatedly to determine ready state.

Comment: Like @Claus said, I think the best approach is to first check if your bean is ready and the consume the message from the queue. However, keeping these states is in general quit tricky..what happens if your bean is never ready? Are you going to wait forever?

Answer (score 0):

You can write that in a java bean where you combine isReady and doWork method, instead of the Camel loop. Also mind about looping is not a good idea if you need to loop for a very long time. If you are not ready its better to not consume from the AMQ queue but leave the messages in the store.

So you can instead use a route policy that is controlling the route to suspend/resume depending on the ready status.

You can then from the route policy periodically check the isReady and then either suspend/resume the route accordingly.

http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar situation, and addressed it by a self recursive route. I don't know whether there are some down sides for this approach.

```
<route>
  <from uri="activemq:queue:myQueue" />
  <to uri="direct:loopingRoute"/>
</route>

<route>
  <from uri="direct:loopingRoute"/>
  <choice>
    <when>
      <method ref="myService" method="isReady"/>
      <bean ref="myService" method="doWork"/>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      <to uri="direct:loopingRoute"/>
    </otherwise>
  </choice>
</route>
```

---

This was the apporach used by me. While answering the question, one point came into my mind. Does it cause `stack overflow` if recursion is beyond a limit?